# resource pool driver doesn't continuierly move when picking pallets from pallet rack

Tags: anylogic

When it comes to rackpick my resource pool needs about 5 minutes to pick the next pallet from my pallet rack. Why doesn't my resource pool driver continuierly pick the pallets? The driver picks a pallet and give it to the loadpoint and after that he doesn't move for about 5 minutes and then it picks the next pallet.
My delay block time comes from a database and lasts 300 minutes to release the number of pallets. The picking process is very quickly the only problem is the time between picking the pallets.
The pallets were insert by a database. It should pick the pallets without waiting between them.

[image: process]

[image: resourcepool]

[image: rackpick]

[image: database]

Comment: The delay is probably too long... if you want to pick all the pallets you shouldn't use a delay (at least not one with time delay, but instead with stopDelay)

Comment: Okay, thanks. That was also my first thought.